# $b^{\frac{m}{n}}=(b^{\frac{1}{n}})^m=(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ except $b$ is not negative when $n$ is Even.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, arithmetic

The following property, known as Rational number property, is taken from the book (I am following now a days) *College Algebra* by *Raymond A Barnett and Micheal R Ziegler*

I restate,

> $b^{\frac{m}{n}}=(b^{\frac{1}{n}})^m=(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ except $b$ is not negative when $n$ is Even.

**Note:** The restrictions are given only for $b$ and $n$ and not for $m$.

I tried working against the restrictions (given in book)  but since there is no restriction given for $m$, I took value of $m$ arbitrarily. Even though things are going right.

$$((-1)^3)^{\frac{1}{2}} = ((-1)^{\frac{1}{2}})^3$$

$$\sqrt{(-1)^3}=(\sqrt{-1})^3$$

$$\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{-1}  \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1}$$

**Note:** I know that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only and only if, $a \geq 0$ *or* $b \geq 0$ but here I ignored this restriction since this time I am  only verifying the restrictions given in my book. There is no such restriction given in my book $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only and only if, $a \geq 0$ *or* $b \geq 0$

So ignoring the above restriction we get,

$$\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \sqrt{-1}$$

And ultimately we get,

$$i=i$$

Hence the restrictions given in my book are disproved. The questions are,

> **1**-I am thinking that there should has been restriction on $m$ along with $b$ and $n$.
>
> **2**-Or, following restriction should has been given,
>
> $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only and only if, $a \geq 0$ *or* $b \geq 0$

[excuse for English]

Am i right?

Comment: I can't find the word "only" in the quoted claim, so it's only given as sufficient condition, not as necessary condition. Thus you haven't disproved the condition in the book; what you have disproved is the (not claimed) assumption that it is a necessary condition.

Comment: Didn't get you! Be more lucid.

Comment: The quoted sentence says "if the conditions are fulfilled, then the claim holds." That's known as a sufficient condition. It does *not* say "if the conditions are not fulfilled, then the claim doesn't hold". That would be a necessary condition. Since only the sufficient condition was claimed, the *only* way to disprove the claim would be to find a case where the conditions are fulfilled but the formula doesn't hold. None of your examples qualify, since they all use $b=-1\notin\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Why don't do post it as an answer. The definitions you gave of **Sufficient condition** and **necessary condition** are new to me and interesting.

Comment: OK, I've posted it as answer (with a slight extension).

Comment: @Sufyan: If English is not your first language, you are welcome to add the problem in your native tongue to the post, and use the `(translation-request)` tag. Hopefully, one of our users who is proficient in both languages will be able to provide a translation. (Especially important is a correct translation of the quote from the book. The whole post rests on the meaning of that.)

Comment: Do you see any mistake in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted sentence says "if the conditions are fulfilled, then the claim holds." That's known as a sufficient condition. It does not say "if the conditions are not fulfilled, then the claim doesn't hold". That would be a necessary condition. Since only the sufficient condition was claimed, the only way to disprove the claim would be to find a case where the conditions are fulfilled but the property doesn't hold.

What you *did* disprove by counterexample was the (not claimed) assumption that the condition is necessary. That is, there are cases which do not fulfil the condition but still the property holds.

However there are simpler counterexamples for the claim being necessary; for example, $m=n=1$ is an obvious counterexample (violating the condition that $n$ is even, but clearly $b^{\frac{1}{1}}=(b^{\frac11})^1=(b^1)^{\frac11}$ for any $b$).

Comment: I have edited my title little bit. You can see it

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: I notice that you also edited the quote. That means either the original quote or the current quote is not correct (because there's only one thing that's in the book). In particular, your edit changed the meaning of the quote.